gRPC Observability in Python for aio.server
I would like to publish metrics of my gRPC services for a prometheus server. The names of metrics must commit opentelemtry semantic conventions.
I have installed grpcio-observability and follow its example but using a grpc aio.server and I would say that it is not supported, right?
